# Importing library with native module causes Vite build to fail?

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit, rollupjs

I've tried everything to get this to work. The module `resvg` uses Rust under the hood to transform SVGs into PNGs. Everything works fine if I run `npm run dev`, but when I start to build it, it gets to using the svelte adapter for node, and then fails.

```
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/endpoints/api/og/_server.ts.js            613.45 kB

Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
error during build:
RollupError: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (file:///C:/Users/-/Documents/DailyTrivia/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2125:30)
    at Module.error (file:///C:/Users/-/Documents/DailyTrivia/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13316:16)
    at Module.tryParse (file:///C:/Users/-/Documents/DailyTrivia/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13993:25)
    at Module.setSource (file:///C:/Users/-/Documents/DailyTrivia/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13603:39)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///C:/Users/-/Documents/DailyTrivia/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23569:20)
```

Commenting out the import for `resvg` causes the build to succesfully complete. I looked in the source for resvg and it imports `resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc.node`. This is where I think the error is. I tried adding exclusions and a plugin to my vite.config.js, but that didn't work.

```
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import fs from "fs";
import native from "rollup-plugin-native";





function rawFonts(ext: any[]) {
  return {
    name: "vite-plugin-raw-fonts",
    transform(code: any, id: any) {
      if (ext.some((e) => id.endsWith(e))) {
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(id);
        return { code: `export default ${JSON.stringify(buffer)}`, map: null };
      }
    },
  };

};
const config = {
  plugins: [
    sveltekit(),
    rawFonts([".ttf"]),
    native({
      platformName:
        "${dirname}/precompiled/${nodePlatform}-${nodeArchitecture}/node.napi.node",
      //platformName: "${dirname}/${basename}-${nativePlatform}-${nativeArchitecture}.node",
    }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["@resvg/resvg-js"]
    },
  },
};
export default defineConfig(config);
```

I added `moduleResolution:node` to my tsconfig, and it still doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: I believe the `build.rollupOptions.external` should be `["@resvg/resvg-js"]` (i.e. without the leading slash).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I tried all different possible variations, none worked.

Comment: Mmm... please, can you share the line you use to import this module?

Comment: `import Resvg from '@resvg/resvg-js'`

Comment: Checking on NPM webpage, shouldn't it be `import { Resvg } from '@resvg/resvg-js'`? Have you also tried setting `build.rollupOptions.output.globals: { "@resvg/resvg-js": "Resvg" }`?

Comment: Still getting the same error: 
const config:UserConfigExport = {
  plugins: [
     ...
  ],
  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["@resvg/resvg-js"],
      output: {
        globals: { "@resvg/resvg-js": "Resvg" },
      },
    },
  },
};
export default defineConfig(config);

Comment: I'm unable to replicate it in my local. If I import this module, I get the same error as you but as soon as I fill the `build.rollupOptions.external` param, it vanishes and lets me compile it. Granted I do nothing with the module but console.log it but the build seems to be importing it correctly. Perhaps, could you create a minimal repository with the error so I can take a look?

Comment: Good idea. I'll do this right now.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! All I had to do was uninstall and then reinstall the package. Must have gotten corrupted somehow! Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad it had an easy fix :-)

Comment: I have the same problem and everything that is indicated here does not help me